# OCaml: Instantiating parameterized type imported from another module

Tags: ocaml

I have a module in one file that contains the type `type move = Move of int`. In another file, I open this module and can refer to the type by `ModuleName1.move`. But is it possible to construct an instance of this type in the second file, given that I'd have to use the `Move i` syntax, and since that `Move` parameter/keyword isn't really accessible from the second file?

Here's the module where I want to instantiate the type from the first module (which is called Game and contains the type `type move = Move of int`. It's right at the end, in the next_move function, that I want to construct a (Move 0) and pass it to make_tree, however it doesn't recognize `Move` since it's a parameterized type constructor from the other module:

```
#use "sig_player.ml" ;;
#use "game.ml" ;;
    module TestAIPlayer =
        struct
          module PlayerGame = Game
          open PlayerGame

          let max_depth = 4 ;;

          (* Data Definition *)
          type tree = Node of PlayerGame.state * PlayerGame.move * tree list ;;

          let rec make_tree (root: PlayerGame.state * PlayerGame.move) (d: int): tree =
            let (s, m) = root in
            let lms = PlayerGame.legal_moves s in
            match lms, d with
            | [], _ | _, 0 -> Node (s, m, [])
            | _, _ -> Node (s, m, (List.map
                        (fun mv -> make_tree ((PlayerGame.next_state s mv), mv) (d - 1))
                        lms)) ;;

          let compare_node (n1: PlayerGame.move * float) (n2: PlayerGame.move * float)
            (comp: 'a -> 'a -> 'a): PlayerGame.move * float =
            match n1, n2 with
            | (m1, f1), (m2, f2) -> if (comp f1 f2) = f1 then n1 else n2 ;;

          let rec minimax (t: tree) (mm: bool): PlayerGame.move * float =
            match t with
            | Node (s, m, []) -> (m, PlayerGame.estimate_value s)
            | Node (s, m, children) -> let propagated = List.map
                                    (fun c -> minimax c (not mm)) children in
                                    (match mm with
                                    | true -> List.fold_right
                                              (fun x y -> compare_node x y max)
                                              propagated (m, neg_infinity)
                                    | false -> List.fold_right
                                               (fun x y -> compare_node x y min)
                                               propagated (m, infinity)) ;;

           let next_move s = minimax (make_tree (s, (Move 0)) max_depth) true ;;

        end ;;


        module AIPlayer = (TestAIPlayer : PLAYER with module PlayerGame := Game) ;;
```

Comment: Why isn't `Move` accessible from the second file? Do you have a signature where there's just `type move` written?

Comment: Can you show some code where you're getting an error trying to instantiate a `move` value? That would help us debug.

Comment: I added some code

Comment: Sorry, what's the exact error message?

Comment: `Error: This expression has type TestGame.move
       but an expression was expected of type PlayerGame.move = Game.move`

Comment: Well then you have two types `move` defined and you're using one instead of the other. You should put a Minimal Working Example (and by doing so you may find your error, actually).

Comment: Is the error referring to the line near the end of the code, `let next_move s = ... Move 0 ...`? It looks like the `Move` constructor is creating a value of type `TestGame.move`. I don't see a `TestGame` module in your code so I'm not sure how that's happening. Need to see more code, especially anything that deals with `TestGame` before your current snippet.

Comment: yes - TestGame is the module I'm importing from the other file

Comment: The problem is I want to create an instance of the type from TestGame, but I'm not sure if it's possible to import this type definition over from TestGame

Comment: I'm repeating myself but create a Minimal Working (or in your case not working) Example and help will be provided. In the current case your problem is completely unclear and your question will be flagged if you don't improve it.